# Could not find gem 'spree-paypal-express' with spree 1.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, spree

Hi I have installed and working Spree 1.1.1. and want to integrate PayPal to the engine. and when i am trying to install 'spree_paypal_express' the console is showing the below message please help me out.

```
Could not find gem 'spree-paypal-express (>= 0) x86-mingw32' in the gems available on this machine.
```

Comment: Please post a snippet from your Gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible issues with this.

First, there may be an issue with your Gemfile. For example,

-- the gem may not be in the gemfile,

-- you may have misspelled the name of the gem in your gemfile

-- you may have extra whitespace in the gem name (e.g., `gem 'spree-paypal-express '` <- note extra space)

Here are some things you can try (after checking the above first to make sure your Gemfile is correct):

- Remove all your gems (go to the gems folder of your ruby, remove the specifications folder and the gems folder -- or create a new gemset using rvm)
- gem list should be more or less empty
- gem install bundler
- And try to bundle install again from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I have manually downloaded zip folder from github repository and extracted.
by going in to the directory run `gem build spree_paypal_express.gemspec` 
then it will generate some files in which **spree_paypal_express-1.1.0.gem** will be one of them.
so later run gem install `spree_paypal_express-1.1.0.gem`

then you are ready to go... you can check by `gem list`